# How to see from what source data comes from in ms access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have to figure out from what source the value of the field is coming from.

I have tried to search by name `txtRun` and by Control source name `Run` in vb classes, but there are nothing matched values.

Are there any ways to do that?

[image: Field in design view]

[image: Properties for that field]

Comment: Check the data source of the form and then find `Run` in that data source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simple:

If the control source is *run*, the value comes from the column *run* of the form's record source. The record source can either be a table or a query.